# Sum of a multi index series (really dumb question)

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{l}  (x_iy_i + x_jy_j)  = k \sum_{i=1}^l x_iy_i$$

I have to find $k$.
I know the question is really stupid, but for some reason  I am unable to solve this.

Comment: $l = 1$ requires $k = 0$, assuming $x_i,y_i \neq 0$. So I guess you need some more conditions.

Comment: Split the left hand side, $$\sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^l x_i y_i + \sum_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^l x_jy_j.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel, like I said it was trivial :)

Comment: No, it is not, you must prove that exactly every term is repeated $k$ times.

Comment: @Ritz: That isn't actually a problem.

Comment: @Ritz: you established a first valid result: $k(1)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: add and remove the forbidden ($i\ne j$) terms.

$$
\sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i \neq j}}^{l} x_iy_i=
\sum_{\substack{i,j=1}}^{l} x_iy_i-\sum_{\substack{i,j=1 \\ i = j}}^{l} x_iy_i=
\sum_{j=1}^l\sum_{\substack{i=1}}^{l} x_iy_i-\sum_{i=1}^{l} x_iy_i=(l-1)\sum_{i=1}^{l} x_iy_i.$$

Same for $x_jy_j$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: For example, either $i=1$ or $j$ may be equal to $1.$ So, how many terms  containing $x_1y_1$ will there be?

If you want to get an idea, start by looking at various small values of $l,$ and computing the left-hand side explicitly.

For the proof, contrast with $$\sum_{I,j=1}^l(x_iy_I+x_jy_j),$$ which is easier to calculate.